# Exportar para banco de dados

Tags: mysql, jsp, acentuação, exportação

Carrego 3 Strings a partir de um CMS.

```
String Data da Noticia
String Titulo da Noticia
String Texto da Noticia
```

Dentro de um *loop*, crio a *query* de inserir com essas 3 strings.

Só que estou tendo alguns problemas.

1º) A string Texto da Noticia, tem caracteres como "-" e " ' " para resolver, usei `replace`. Mas teria alguma forma de inserir, sem ter que tirar esses caracteres do texto da noticia?

2º)Caracteres com acentuação do texto da noticia como "ç" , "é" , "á" estão sendo salvo no banco como um " ? "

Tentei usar isso:

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Mas não resolve. No banco também setei para utf8 e unicod.

Alguém sabe como resolver esses 2 problemas?

Comment: Que tipo de banco de dados você está usando? Que linguagem de programação está usando?

Comment: Carrego o conteúdo de um CMS em uma pagina JSP. E exporto para banco MySQL.

Comment: Tente exportar as strings em UTF-8 ou Unicode. Tive um problema similar com o SQL Server e esta "conversão" funcionou.

Comment: Como faz para exportar nesses formatos?

Comment: Na pergunta o Bruno está usando MySQL, isso é valido também nele?

Answer (score 1):

O MySQL é totalmente capaz de salvar caracteres especiais. Aconselho você ao invés de utilizar concatenação de strings para formar um *script*.

Ex :

```
string script = "INSERT INTO TABELA (ID, NOME, IDADE) VALUES ("+ id +",'"+ nome +"'," + idade +")"
```

Usar variáveis para passar a informação.

Ex :

```
string script = "INSERT INTO TABELA (ID, NOME, IDADE) VALUES (@ID, @NOME, @IDADE)" 

var command = new SqlCommand(sql);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOME", nome);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDADE", idade);
```